# Отображение страницы только при полной загрузке

Tags: asp.net, c#

Как показать страницу только тогда, когда она полностью загрузилась?

Comment: Обычно стараются делать наоборот)

Comment: Наоборот - это не наоборот, только наоборот:)

Просто это нужно именно для моего случая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как на счет поставить `display: none` для `body`, а после загрузки (`onload`, `ready`, используя все что-угодно) установить `display: block`?

Comment: а на мобильном устройстве такой скрит сработает?

Comment: смотря на каком, но на старых, без поддержки JS - нет

Answer (score 0):

[Смотрим](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/), устанавливаем, радуемся. Теперь меняем жизненную позицию и пытаемся разобраться в том, как ajax делает запросы и по сигналу complete отображаем содержимое.